# Halt Netbackup from doing any Backups, but still allow Restore

Tags: netbackup

My backup system is currently shut down do the library being broken.  I am going to attempt to repair the library, but want to make sure none of the current data that is past the retention period gets over written.  Is there a simple way that I can start netbackup, but put a halt on any back processes before they start?

Comment: I did cancel all jobs from the GUI, but wondering if there something I can do make sure no more start. I Don't think any of the policy's have an open window right now, but wondering what additional lock I can do other than the physical switch on the tapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduled jobs can be prevented with:

```
bin\admincmd\nbpemreq -suspend_scheduling

bin\admincmd\nbpemreq -resume_scheduling
```